# Which Year's Best Science Fiction contained Cilia of Gold, The Remoras

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space-exploration

What year's best science fiction had the story Cilia of Gold, Remoras on the outside of an immense interstellar travelling planetoid, and a dormant alien who arrives on Earth and mistakes smiling humans as agressors and activates a destructive force?

Answer (score 12):

Since you know it has Cilia of Gold & 'Remoras on the outside of an immense interstellar traveling planetoid', AND it's a Year's Best SciFi, I think I can conclusively say its:
[The Year's Best Science Fiction Twelfth Annual Collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Year%27s_Best_Science_Fiction%3a_Twelfth_Annual_Collection) from 1995, since two of the stories are named **Cilia of Gold** and **Remoras**.

I'm not sure of the last story, but hopefully the story names will give it to you.

Stealing from Wikipedia, here's the list of Authors & Stories:

- Ursula K. Le Guin:"Forgiveness Day"
- Robert Reed:"The Remoras"
- Maureen F. McHugh:"Nekropolis"
- Nancy Kress:"Margin of Error"
- Stephen Baxter:"Cilia-of-gold"
- William Sanders:"Going After Old Man Alabama"
- Michael F. Flynn:"Melodies of the Heart"
- Terry Bisson:"The Hole in the Hole"
- Pat Cadigan:"Paris In June"
- George Turner:"Flowering Mandrake"
- Joe Haldeman:"None So Blind"
- Greg Egan:"Cocoon"
- Mike Resnick:"Seven Views of Olduvai Gorge"
- Geoff Ryman:"Dead Space for the Unexpected"
- Michael Bishop:"Cri de Coeur"
- Howard Waldrop:"The Sawing Boys"
- Ursula K. Le Guin:"The Matter of Seggri"
- Eliot Fintushel:"Ylem"
- Katherine Kerr:"Asylum"
- Walter Jon Williams:"Red Elvis"
- Mary Rosenblum:"California Dreamer"
- Lisa Goldstein:"Split Light"
- Brian Stableford:"Les Fleurs du Mal"

Comment: That is definitely it!

Comment: Glad I was able to help; don't forget to 'accept' the answer if it's correct.